# Symfony 2 Profiler: Get total execution time

Tags: php, symfony, profiler, symfony-2.3

In my custom controller function I get information about requests as follows:

```
public function customProfilerControllerFunction {
    $profiler = $this->container->get('profiler');
    $requests = $profiler->find('', '', 10000, '', $start, $end);
    ...
}
```

My goal is to get the total execution of each query. How can I access the total execution time of each request made within my custom profiler controller function?

Comment: Can you explain ? You want the execution time of each mysql request ?